# STM32 programmer randomly reads zeroes and cannot write

Tags: stm32

Reading memory with the programmer will randomly read zero words from various memory addresses. Writing flash or option bytes will fail. In some cases the MCU will disconnect from the programmer, immediately or randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Add the recommended 100nF decoupling capacitor to the NRST pin. My hand holding the TagConnect programming probe was coupling 60Hz noise into the NRST pin, causing the MCU to randomly reset.